# What should I use for the filepath if I'm developing from my desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, initialization, flowplayer

I'm having an extremely difficulty time getting the flowplayer to show up and the worst part is I have no idea what is wrong because I'm not getting any error messages!

I have an external javascript file:

C:/desktop/mysite/js/jq/plugins.js

calling $f() from:

C:/desktop/mysite/thirdparty/flowplayer/flowplayer.js

the swf files also live there...

I'm working on file/desktop (no localhost or webserver)

```
   $(video.id).flowplayer("thirdparty/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.1.15.swf", {
    clip:{
     ....
    },

    // min Flash version 
    version:[9,115],

     // older versions will see a custom message 
     onFail:function(){
       alert("Failed!");
     },

     onError:function(errCode,errMsg){
       alert(errCode+errMsg);
     }
   });
```

I don't know what path to use for the SWFs to get them to load, is the path relative to the javascript (plugins.js) that calls $f() or is it relative to the path of the flowplayer.js ??

*bangs head on wall*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the absolute path?

```
$(video.id).flowplayer("file://c:/desktop/mysite/thirdparty/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.1.15.swf"...
```

Comment: ive tried this, but since Im not getting any information or errors, I cant tell whats wrong, all i know its not working =/

Comment: @codeninja it could be that this is failing due to local file system access restrictions in place for security reasons. Is there no way you can put this onto a - local or remote - web server?

Comment: yeah there is but its a bit of a pain. i downloaded the demo version of flowplayer and it seems to work fine on the desktop

Comment: ok javascript is disabled when seen on local files... on ie you would have a yellow bar on top asking for access, not sure about firefox or other browsers. otherwise look for a localhost solution so you dnt really need a website,webhost to preview it.

Comment: @codeninja hmm, it really could be that this works only in a server context. I'm not sure but i'd recommend to test that first.

Answer (score 1):

replace `thirdparty/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.1.15.swf` with `thirdparty\flowplayer\flowplayer-3.1.15.swf`

if you are planning to put that on a web page then change the slashes back to forward slashes.

Comment: Nope, that won't be necessary. The browser will be able to translate it automatically.